# ListFragment's onCreateView(), how to force to invoke?

Tags: android

I am using the android example app FragmentPagerSupport.java to implement the slide effects between pages. Each page contains a HTTP image which is loaded by a thread. My fragment's onCreateView() is doing the loading stuff for the image. Now my problem is, I don't know how to draw the loaded image bitmap onto the ImageView which is created in onCreateView, any idea to enforce the Fragment's onCreateView to be called?

```
       @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("第 #" + mNum + " 篇");
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final String pic = FragmentPagerSupport.items.get(mNum).thumb;
        Log.e("tag ", "on create view on");
        MyItem mi = FragmentPagerSupport.items.get(mNum);
        if (mi.bm != null) {
            Log.e("tag", "setbitmap for " + mNum);
            iv.setImageBitmap(mi.bm);
        } else {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    int m = mNum;
                    final Bitmap bm = loadBitmap(pic);
                    MyItem mi = FragmentPagerSupport.items.get(m);
                    mi.bm = bm;                 
                    Log.e("tab", "finishing load bitmap for " + m);
                    // here I want the bitmap can be drawn to the ImageView which is inside the fragment.
                }
            }).start();
        }

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for this AsyncTask class:

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
ImageView bmImage;

public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
    this.bmImage = bmImage;
}

protected Bitmap doInBackground(Strings... args) {
    Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                int m = Integer.parse(args[0]);
                String pic = args[1];
    try {
                final Bitmap bm = loadBitmap(pic);
                MyItem mi = FragmentPagerSupport.items.get(m);
                mi.bm = bm;                 
                Log.e("tab", "finishing load bitmap for " + m);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mIcon11;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
}
```

and use as:

```
new DownloadImageTask(iv).execute(mNum.toString(),pic);
```